# Maximum values in dependent picklist

Tags: dependent-picklist

the maximum values in a picklist is 1000, but which is the maximum in dependent picklist? If I add 1000 values the dependent field is disabled

Answer (score 4):

A controlling field can have up to 300 values. If a field is both a controlling field and dependent picklist, it can’t contain more than 300 values.

See the docs also: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_dependent_field_considerations.htm&language=en